# Data frame imported from excel treats "< " as NA

Tags: r, special-characters

I am importing a large set of numerical data to R from excel. The data is chemical composition numbers, and I frequently have values which are "< 1", for example. Any time I have a "< 1" in the data frame, R is reading/outputting it as NA.

It seems this is being done as the excel file is read, so my attempts at using gsub to replace the "< " with "" are not working since the number is not being treated as a numeric from the start.

I'd like to pull this data and have anything that is "< 1" simply be "1". But like I said, it is being imported as NA and I don't know what to do.

I'm quite new to R so please bear with my limited ability to clearly define my problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `<1 ` is not numerical data, but of type character.. have you tried reading the excel-column as character?

Comment: How many columns does the dataset have, and how many of these should be numeric? One approach would be to read everything in as a string, do the replacement, and the coerce to numeric. Alternately, if the only missingness arises from values that are <1, you could just set all missing values in the numeric columns to 1. I'd be happy to explain either approach.

Comment: What commands are you using to import the data? It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. It's hard to help if we don't even know what code you are running.

Comment: My spreadsheet contains 15 sheets, each of which is comprised of 3-25 columns of data. Each column may or may not contain "< " signs. I need the "< " removed and all #s to be stored as numerics so that the values can be graphed.

Answer (score 4):

read the column as character/text

**sample data (./test.xlsx)**

[image]

**code**

```
df <- readxl::read_excel( "./test.xlsx", sheet = 1, col_types = c("text") )
df
# number
#   <chr> 
# 1 1     
# 2 2     
# 3 3     
# 4 <1    
# 5 3 

#post-processing
library( dplyr )
df %>% mutate( number = gsub("<", "", number ) %>% as.numeric )
# # A tibble: 5 x 1
#   number
#    <dbl>
# 1      1
# 2      2
# 3      3
# 4      1
# 5      3
```

Comment: This solution gets me 1/2 way there, but I have many columns in my spreadsheet. Is there is broad way of telling R to go into each column and replace the "< ", without having to call the column by name? 

I have 15 sheets each containing columns with unique names and so I cannot name them in code each time...

Comment: @SRO yes, you can. but that s a different quenstion (which has also been answered, so use search)